# Change font size of chart's tooltips

Tags: charts, visualforce-charting

I want to change chart's tooltips font size.

I found this page [Visual Charts - Axis Title change font size](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F0000000992QIAQ) that suggests using id and javascript. I found that apex:chartTips has "id" attribute too, so I tried the suggested method. But it didn't work.

Is there any way to change chart tooltips' font size?

The method I tried is as follows:

Apex code:

```
<apex:barSeries....>
   <apex:chartTips id="chartTipsId" height="100" width="150" rendererFn="renderTable"/>
</apex:barSeries>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('chartTipsId').className = 'chartTipsClass';
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.chartTipsClass{
    font-size: 20px;
 }
 </style>
```

Comment: The link you found is misleading because the `apex:chartTips` element configures the tooltips but is not directly rendered in the page. The tooltips are drawn by Ext.js JavaScript code. The emitted HTML appears to used fixed CSS class names but I couldn't get the tooltip appearance to change when defining alternate CSS styles for those. Note that trying to figure this out is reverse engineering of implementation detail that Salesforce reserve the right to change.

Comment: @KeithC Thank you for your reply. So there is no way I could simply change the tooltips design...

Comment: There probably is a simple way - I couldn't find it but perhaps you or someone else can.